# London Explorer Pass - Waiting times

Tags: london

I'm thinking about buying the London Explorer Pass for three atractions:

London Eye, Wembley Stadium and Westminster Abbey.

What is the average time wait with the Explorer pass? 
Is there a different waiting line from people who acquire the tickets at the location?

Thanks.

Edit:

There were no separate lines at any of the locations below: 
London Eye; 
Wembley Stadium; 
Westminster Abbey.

Comment: Wait times will vary a lot by time of day, day of week, and season

Comment: I don’t think there’s a separate waiting line at each location, but you should save time because you won’t have to queue to buy entry tickets. You can email the London Explorer Pass Team to get a definitive answer https://www.londonexplorerpass.com/contact/

Comment: VTC: too broad, and affected by many factors: purchasers have the option of paying (more) for skip the line tickets, priority tickets, fast track. OP would need to narrow the focus.